# Making a SQL query for Average Function

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL query to list the vendors who have more invoices than the average number of invoices per vendor. So far I've come up with two queries but i am not sure either one is true or not. If anyone can help me out please.

```
SELECT VENDOR_ID,COUNT(INVOICE_ID), ROUND(AVG(INVOICE_ID), 2)
FROM INVOICES
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
HAVING COUNT(INVOICE_ID) > AVG(INVOICE_ID)
ORDER BY AVG(INVOICE_ID);

SELECT VENDOR_ID,COUNT(INVOICE_ID), ROUND(AVG(INVOICE_ID), 2)
FROM INVOICES
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID
HAVING AVG(INVOICE_ID) > (SELECT AVG(INVOICE_ID) FROM INVOICES)
ORDER BY AVG(INVOICE_ID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Edited as per Arth's comment

So the average number of invoices per vendor would be:

```
SELECT cast(COUNT(Invoice_ID) as float) / COUNT(DISTINCT Vendor_Id)
FROM INVOICES
```

now lets put that into your requirements

```
SELECT Vendor_Id, COUNT(Invoice_Id)
FROM INVOICES
GROUP BY Vendor_Id
HAVING COUNT(Invoice_ID) > 
              (SELECT cast(COUNT(Invoice_ID) as float) / COUNT(DISTINCT Vendor_Id) FROM INVOICES)
```

Comment: That's not how COUNT works.. you'd need COUNT(DISTINCT x) for at least the vendors, COUNT counts everything that isn't null as 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a MySQL question not SQL-Server.. these are two separate database engines. Please choose the appropriate tag.

First of all it sounds like you want to average the number of invoices, not the invoice id. To get the average number of invoices:

```
  SELECT AVG(c.invoice_count)
    FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) invoice_count
      FROM invoices i
  GROUP BY i.vendor_id
         ) c
```

I'd probably JOIN this in to use as a condition:

```
  SELECT vendor_id, COUNT(*) invoice_count
    FROM invoices
    JOIN ( 
     SELECT AVG(c.invoice_count) avg_invoice_count
       FROM (
       SELECT COUNT(*) invoice_count
         FROM invoices
     GROUP BY vendor_id
            ) c
         ) a
GROUP BY vendor_id
  HAVING invoice_count > a.avg_invoice_count    
ORDER BY invoice_count DESC
```

As pointed out by Steve Ford, you could calculate the AVG as follows:

```
  SELECT vendor_id, COUNT(*) invoice_count
    FROM invoices
    JOIN ( 
     SELECT CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT)/COUNT(DISTINCT vendor_id) avg_invoice_count
       FROM invoices
         ) a
GROUP BY vendor_id
  HAVING invoice_count > a.avg_invoice_count    
ORDER BY invoice_count DESC
```

Comment: You need to cast one of your numbers to float or decimal otherwise you'll be using integer arithmatic e.g. 1 / 2 = 0!